# frame busting as csrf

Tags: javascript, csrf, static-analysis

I'm analyzing an application using a static code analyzer and it is flagging a frame busting script as if it were a CSRF vulnerability, I have been researching why this is happening but no luck, so if anyone knows what's going on I would appreciate the help, this is the part of the script that has the issue:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (self == top) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            top.location = self.location;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side frame busting techniques are unsafe ("frame buster busting"). See e.g. https://www.owasp.org/images/0/0e/OWASP_AppSec_Research_2010_Busting_Frame_Busting_by_Rydstedt.pdf

If you rely only on the above frame-busting code, a malicious person could still manage to display your site in an iframe and employ "click-jagging" to let an unsuspecting victim perform an action on your website (i.e. send an authorised request to perform a harmful action without being aware of it = Cross site request 'forgery').

Comment: So I realize that it is not perfect protection against clickjacking, but I guess my question is: Am I introducing a vulnerability by using frame-busting?

Comment: @FelipeGuerra You don't introduce a new vulnerability, but you also don't prevent one (clickjagging) and as such, your frame-busting code might provide a false sense of security.